# Why are Hubble images "Cut"

Tags: space, deep-sky-observing, hubble-telescope

Whenever you take a look at a photo that is taken by hubble, 
Lets say M87 or Eagle Nebula or maybe Ultra Deep space field,

The Image is always "Cut"

Like this :
 [image]

or this

[image]

I want to know reason for this ,

Any ideas?

I think it's during photo capture or processing error... or no details about elements to color?

Comment: It is because of an old instrument, now replaced. One quarter of one quarter of the image had better resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "stair-step" pattern visible in the first image is characteristic of the the Hubble's [Wide Field and Planetary Camera 2 (WFPC2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Field_and_Planetary_Camera_2). This pattern is created by the arrangement of the four CCD chips. [This image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Field_and_Planetary_Camera_2#mediaviewer/File:Jfader_hubble.jpg) shows how the three larger "wide field" chips and the smaller, single "planetary camera" chip are arranged to create the pattern.

The bottom picture appears to be a slice of the original Hubble Deep Field, which was also captured with WFPC2.

So the answer, for these two images, is that the shape of the image is an artifact of image capture.

However, in general, finished images such as these could take up any arbitrary shape. Many of the modern images contain data from multiple views, multiple cameras, even multiple telescopes all drizzled together using specialized photo processing software.

Comment: What purpose did the planetary camera chip serve relative to the three wide field chips?  Why was it different?